# how do i get single file size in listView

Tags: android, android-studio

i'am trying to display all files in devices with specific extensions, but problem is i got wrong size on all files, it only display 22 bytes to all files in listView. and i want to get default picture like zip image, ISO image and image of APK.. where i do wrong

```
public class NotificationsFragment extends Fragment {
ListView listView;
String[] items;

private NotificationsViewModel notificationsViewModel;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    notificationsViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NotificationsViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false);
    listView = root.findViewById(R.id.app_list);
    runtimePermission();
    //final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_notifications);
    notificationsViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            //textView.setText(s);
        }
    });
    return root;
}

public void runtimePermission() {
    Dexter.withContext(getContext()).withPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport multiplePermissionsReport) {
                    showList();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> list, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                    permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();
}

public ArrayList<File> findList(File file) {

    ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    for (File singleFile : files) {
        if (singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()) {
            arrayList.addAll(findList(singleFile));
        } else {
            if (singleFile.getName().endsWith(".apk") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".iso") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".exe") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".rar") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".zip")) {
                arrayList.add(singleFile);
            }
        }
    }
    return arrayList;
}

private void showList() {
    final ArrayList<File> myApps = findList(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    items = new String[myApps.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i<myApps.size(); i++){
        items[i] = myApps.get(i).getName().toString();

    }

    customAdapter customAdapter = new customAdapter();
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}

public String readableFileSize(long size) {
    if (size <= 0)
        return "0";
    final String[] units = new String[] { "byte", "kb", "mb", "gb", "tb" };
    int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(size) / Math.log10(1024));
    return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(size / Math.pow(1024, digitGroups)) + " " + units[digitGroups];
}

class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.download_item, null);
        TextView songName = myView.findViewById(R.id.download_name);
        ShapeableImageView appImage = myView.findViewById(R.id.download_img);
        TextView sizeApp = myView.findViewById(R.id.app_details);
        TextView install = myView.findViewById(R.id.install_btn);
        songName.setSelected(true);
        songName.setText(items[position]);
        sizeApp.setText(readableFileSize(items.length));
```

// it gives 22 bytes to all list, which is not true

//How to get default image of file into listview??

```
        return myView;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items` is your list. So `items.length` is the length of the list, not the length of a file. Try `sizeApp.setText(readableFileSize(items[position].length))`.

Comment: this helped, each file have its size. but i messed up on how to calculate file size, it only show byte even a file has 200mb, it shows 200byte. thank you